# Succour with Card Game Implementation

Tags: python

I've been working on a Python implementation for a card game, and I'm encountering some unexpected results. The game involves assigning values to cards based on their rank and suit. I suspect there might be a problem in the `play` function that determines the winners of each turn and the final game winners.

Here's a brief overview of the issue:

- The game runs, but the final winners are not consistent with expectations.
- I have a function `card_value(card)` that correctly assigns values to cards based on their rank and suit.
- The `play` function uses a random seed, deals hands, and determines winners at each turn, accumulating points for the final winners.

```
    import random
    from typing import List, Tuple

    SUITS = "♠ ♡ ♢ ♣".split()
    RANKS = "2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 J Q K A".split()

    Card = Tuple[str, str]
    Deck = List[Card]

    def create_deck(shuffle: bool = False) -> Deck:
        deck = [(s, r) for r in RANKS for s in SUITS]
        if shuffle:
            random.shuffle(deck)
        return deck

    def deal_hands(deck: Deck) -> Tuple[Deck, Deck, Deck, Deck]:
        return (deck[0::4], deck[1::4], deck[2::4], deck[3::4])

    def choose(items):
        return random.sample(items, len(items))

    def player_order(names, start=None):
        if start is None:
            start = random.choice(names)
        start_idx = names.index(start)
        return names[start_idx:] + names[:start_idx]

    def card_value(card: Card) -> int:
        rank = card[1]
        if rank in {'J', 'Q', 'K'}:
            value = 10
        elif rank == 'A':
            value = 11
        else:
            value = int(rank)

        if card[0] in {'♠', '♣'}:
            value *= 2
        return value

    def play(seed_value: int) -> str:
        random.seed(seed_value)
        deck = create_deck(shuffle=True)
        names = "P1 P2 P3 P4".split()
        hands = {n: h for n, h in zip(names, deal_hands(deck))}
        start_player = random.choice(names)
        turn_order = player_order(names, start=start_player)
        points = {name: 0 for name in names}

        while any(hands[start_player]):
            card = {name: choose(hands[name])[0] for name in turn_order}
            max_value = max(card_value(card[name]) for name in turn_order)
            winners = [name for name in turn_order if card_value(card[name]) == max_value]
            for winner in winners:
                points[winner] += 1

            for name in turn_order:
                hands[name].remove(card[name])

        game_winner = [name for name in names if points[name] == max(points.values())]
        return " ".join(sorted(game_winner))

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        print(play(999)) # output P4 - sholud be P2 P4
        print(play(31)) # output P2 - this one is ok
        print(play(72)) # output P1 P3 - sholud be P3
        print(play(19)) # output P2 - this one is ok
        print(play(98765432)) # output  P1 - sholud be P1 P2 P3
```

First, the function card_value(card) was written, which, given a card, returns its value. Card values correspond to their numerical value from 2 to 10, all face cards (Jack, Queen, King) count as 10 and Ace as 11. If the card's color is black (i.e. club or spades suit), its value is equal to double.

Then I wrote a function play(seed_value) that returns a string with the sorted and space-separated winners of the game (for example, “P1 P4”). The winners of each turn, those with the most valuable cards, receive one point, and the final winners are those with the most points. The seed method (from the random number module) should be used to initialize the pseudo-random number generator using random.seed(seed_value).

The game goes like this:
We deal each player 13 cards.

- We deal each player 13 cards.
- The first player is then chosen and the players take turns playing their cards.
- Players will randomly play one card each turn until their hands are empty.
- The winner on the turn or in the event of a tie is the one with the most valuable card.
- The winner of the game or winners in case of a tie are determined at the end.

I would appreciate it if you could take a look at the provided code and help me identify any potential issues or improvements. I've included a few test cases at the end of the code.

Comment: Why do you expect those seeds to produce those results?  Debugging/testing might be easier if the arg to `play` were an already-shuffled (or stacked) deck.

Comment: @Samwise - Because I was given the correct results

Comment: By whom?  Predicting the behavior of a given piece of code based on a RNG seed (other than by running it) is pretty difficult.  Random seed results aren't even necessarily consistent across minor Python versions IIRC.

Comment: @Samwise
Initially, the code did not have a play function or a choice. And the task was to write them, and the correct answers were given for comparison.
I've added the code, but my results don't match

Comment: This looks like an excellent opportunity for you to practice your debug skills.. Using a debugger, step through your code and identify where the problem lies..  This will be easier, if you tae the randomness out of your game during debug.

Comment: `print(play(999)) # output P4 - sholud be P2 P4` How do you know this?  How do you know what the output from a specific random seed should be?

Comment: @JohnGordon My computer science professor provided the results

Comment: We need an explanation of what the code **should** do.  Simply telling us that the code should produce certain results for a certain input is not an **explanation**.

Comment: @JohnGordon I added the condition

Comment: I see that your code performs random operations in this order: first it shuffles the deck, then it chooses a starting player, then it chooses a random card from each player's hand until the hands are empty.  Are you sure your professor's code does the random operations in that same exact order?  If your professor's code does them in a different order, for example if it chooses the starting player and _then_ shuffles the deck, you will get different results.

Comment: Expecting certain output based on a random seed input feels like a really poor way to do testing.  I wonder why your professor did it that way.

Comment: @JohnGordon They are probably using an auto-grading program that seeds the random number generator to guarantee repeatable outcomes. Pretty standard for a lot of courses (the Harvard CS50 course uses this for some problem sets)

Comment: @nigh_anxiety Providing a fixed starting deck and player list would be more repeatable/testable.  But the random seed thing is easier, so I guess I see why they did it.  I jumped into this code from the viewpoint of "something is wrong and I want to find out **why**", but the professor's viewpoint is probably more like "I want to grade these homework problems quickly and easily".

Comment: The random seed is being used mostly to ensure the students are implementing the random functions correctly, as that is probably the point of the lesson.

Comment: My English vocabulary is pretty decent, but I had to look up "succour". The site prohibits titles like "I need help" because they are useless; _every question_ on this site could have that title. The point is to get you to provide a useful title instead, not demonstrate your prowess with a thesaurus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appears to be in your implementation of the `choose()` function.

In order to make it function correctly, it should always be taking a sample of size 1 from each player's hand.

```
    def choose(items):
        return random.sample(items, 1)   # Not len(items)!
```

By using `len(items)` for k, you were forcing the pseudo-random number generator to be called additional times whenever `choose(hands[name])` was called.  This meant that other than the first card of the starting player, the players were not choosing the cards expected by the examples given by your professor.

After making that change, I got the expected results:

```
P2 P4
P2
P3
P2
P1 P3 P4
```

Comment: Wait, just realized the last one is wrong....  But the first four are correct.. Investigating.

Comment: I think it should be `random.choice(items)`.  There's no reason to call `sample()`, because you're always choosing one.  Unless... maybe the intended implementation is to sample the entire hand all at once, and then consume cards from the result?

Comment: @JohnGordon  I agree that `random.choice(items)` would make more sense than calling `sample(items,1)`, but I worked it out under the assumption that OP was directed to use `random.sample()` in his directions.  Either way, `random.choice(items)` , with the appropriate change to not get [0] from the function return value gives the same results as  `random.sample(items, 1)`, because under the hood, both functions result in the same internal `_randlower()` function being called once, thereby getting the same pseudorandom sequence.

Comment: @FrefericPather - can you double check that the last seed value and expected results ou have are correct?  I consistently get `P1 P3 P4` for that seed value, whether using `random.choice` or `random.sample` to select the cards for each hand.

Comment: Yes, this is the solution, I asked the professor. I don’t know to what extent this is a correct task, but it is)
thanks for the help @nigh_anxiety